# How to make paypal auto charge my customer on a pay per use pricing plan?

Tags: paypal

My web has a pricing of pay-per-use. Let's say my web process a file for example resizing image.
When my customer sign up they get 100 coins for free.
Each time my customer resize image and sell it it will cost 1 coin. but all of this happens automatically after someone purchases image.

My question is I would like to charge them automatically
for example after the coins of my customer drop below 10 then charge automatically 15 coins ($15) --- $1 per coin (My customer should be able to choose how much coins he/she wants to recharge)
I'm not sure but I think paypal doesn't provide this feature to new customer anymore?

https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/reference-transactions/

What choices do I have? I really need this auto recharge feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference transactions still exist, but have always required approval. The account owner should contact PayPal's business support (not technical support) to inquire about the approval, and explain the business need.

If approved, PayPal can then guide you on which API to best integrate with -- which might be the new v2/vault (note: not v1/vault)